# Push Item to the end of an array

Tags: c#, .net

No, I can't use generic Collections. What I am trying to do is pretty simple actually. In php I would do something like this

```
$foo = [];
$foo[] = 1;
```

What I have in C# is this

```
var foo = new int [10];
// yeah that's pretty much it
```

Now I can do something like `foo[foo.length - 1] = 1` but that obviously wont work. Another option is `foo[foo.Count(x => x.HasValue)] = 1` along with a nullable int during declaration. But there *has* to be a simpler way around this trivial task.

This is homework and I don't want to explain to my teacher (and possibly the entire class) what `foo[foo.Count(x => x.HasValue)] = 1` is and why it works etc.

Comment: You could create your own type that stores the last inserted index for the array, that is really the only way to do it using plain arrays

Comment: That's even more complicated than the Count function! Isn't pushing items into the array kind of the entire purpose of the data structure?

Comment: not that complicated, that's pretty efficient to save the index and flow along it.
but, remember that C# arrays are not re sizable - if you need to resize, you will need to recreate the array and push the items into it (List is implemented like that if im not mistaken)

Comment: Why can't you use generic collections?

Comment: @Achshar no, arrays are created to store data, not to push items to the end.
you will need constant resizing in order to keep pushing values into it. And, if it's not homework of some kind, there's much better options (such as generics / queues...)

Comment: Homework. Teacher expects arrays. And I don't feel like explaining to the entire class why `foo[foo.Count(x => x.HasValue)] = 1` works and what it does.

Comment: @Achshar You are confusing arrays and lists (vectors in c++). Arrays are fixed size and do not keep track of used/unused indexes. You don't "push" items onto an array, they are simply members of the array or they are not. Btw, Nullable is generic, and by creating a nullable array you are, in effect, creating a generic collection.

Comment: `System.Collections.ArrayList` isn't a generic collection. It's not a great choice today, either, but it fits the stated requirements.

Comment: @Achshar so, also a tip for job interviews - it's ok to extend a class. for example, a good answer of "how to count an array with O(1)" is to just keep a count data memeber.

Comment: "Isn't pushing items into the array kind of the entire purpose of the data structure?" - no, the purpose of the data structure is to have a contiguous block of pre-allocated memory that you can easily index. If you want a data structure to easily push elements onto the end, consider a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, or, if you _have_ to, a `System.Collections.List`. Don't try to compare PHP and C# - they have different programming paradigms and the way to solve a problem in one does not necessarily carry over to the other.

Comment: If you can't/won't use a List or ArrayList, the simplest way would be to maintain a separate `int fooCount` and increment it whenever you "add" to the array (you can at least wrap this in a function).

Comment: Also "But there has to be a simpler way around this trivial task." <- there is, it's `List<int>.Add()`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard unfortunately not my decision. The homework assignment specifically requests arrays. I would have used lists too.

Comment: @CompuChip That was a poorly worded statement. What I means was that the point of the array is to store data in a sequence (which is what you said as well). So it would make sense to make the process of adding stuff easier than it apparently is.

Comment: Maybe you can just write your own list hardcoded to int?

Comment: @usr how would that work exactly? Write my own implementation of list? So that it's still array and satisfies the homework parameters? That's rad.

Comment: Why not just have a separate `int count`? This is the trivial language-agnostic solution, not linq.

Comment: @31eee384 Yeah that's what ArielB suggested as well. I guess that's the best option currently.

Comment: `List` uses an array internally anyway, why not use it and call `.ToArray`?

Comment: @Achshar Well, the point is you can't "add" things to arrays, since they're fixed in size.  Of course the way things like `List<T>` work (which do have a concept of "adding" items), is that they internally use an array and keep track of how many items are in it with an integer.  If your assignment forbids you from using the appropriate tools, you're kind of stuck with ugly solutions and hacks.

Comment: @Kyle "Add" was a bad word. From "Add" I mean fill a position. Not add another item and make length 11. I come from js/php and there add/push mean just that put a value at the end of the array without changing the size (well arrays don't have a fixed size there so that doesn't matter).

Comment: @Magnus Welcome to the question, this was a homework assignment that specificaly asked for arrays, so I can't cheat and use lists (which haven't even been covered in class yet) and then call a `.ToArray`.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am going with what you suggested in the very first comment. Can you add it as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @Achshar No problem, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a new class that holds the index of the inserted item:

```
public class PushPopIntArray
{
    private int[] _vals = new int[10];
    private int _nextIndex = 0;

    public void Push(int val)
    {
        if (_nextIndex >= _vals.Length)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No more values left to push");
        _vals[_nextIndex] = val;
        _nextIndex++;
    }

    public int Pop()
    {
        if (_nextIndex <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No more values left to pop");
        _nextIndex--;
        return _vals[_nextIndex];
    }
}
```

You could add overloads to get the entire array, or to index directly into it if you wanted. You could also add overloads or constructors to create different sized arrays, etc.

Comment: Nb. This data-structure is commonly referred to as a *stack*.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, a stack, easily be turned into a queue by modifying the `Pop` method. Really isn't much of a jump to a full blown generic implementation of the built-in `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>`, at least in basic operations.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, arrays cannot be resized dynamically. You can use Array.Resize (but this will probably be bad for performance) or substitute for ArrayList type instead.

Comment: I don't want to resize it. It can stay with 10 elements. I just want to insert an item. No re-sizing involved at all.

Comment: @Achshar "Insert" implies the original items stay there. You can "assign" a specific index, but it will overwrite the original value

Comment: @Achshar so as everyone said, keep an index aside, or initialize the array with something like -99999 (and assume it's not valid value) and search for it...

Comment: @ArielB yeah that's the nullable array + Count() solution that I wrote. I'll have to go with that I think if nothing else comes up.

Comment: @Achshar that's not a pretty solution, extend the array and use an indexer to keep track of the location of the item added. your teacher should like it better. (as it's MUCH more efficient (O(1)) and not O(n)

Comment: It's not a pretty solution because arrays are the wrong type for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @rushonerok yeah, but if it were my choice I would definitely have used lists. But unfortunately it's not :(

Comment: @ArielB Yeah going with that now. No other answer mentions that currently. If you add that as one I'll accept it.

Comment: @Achshar thanks, but i prefer not to take it away from Ron, as he suggested the answer first.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

> But there has to be a simpler way around this trivial task.

Nope.  Not all languages do everything as easy as each other, this is why Collections were invented.  C# <> python <> php <> java.  Pick whichever suits you better, but equivalent effort isn't always the case when moving from one language to another.

Comment: I guess that's the "good" part of a non php language. Since php gets all this hate.

Comment: But there totally is an easy way - use the collection designed for the task. `List<T>` is a drop-in replacement for `int[]`. The only thing stopping you is an arbitrary homework requirement, for which you can hardly blame C#.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Not blaming the language. I was just curious if there was an equivalant to the php concept. If there is not then cool, no harm done here.

Comment: @Achshar I'm saying that there *is* an equivalent. It's `List`. PHP uses the word "array" for the datastructure that C# calls a List.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Equivalent being equivalant to `$foo[] = 1` method of adding values to array. Which is what the question is about.

Comment: The *equivalent* to that php code is `myList.Add(1);`. A php "array" is a [much more complex data-structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) than the structure that C# calls "array". This is just semantics at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`foo[foo.Length]` won't work because foo.Length index is outside the array.
Last item is at index `foo.Length - 1`

After that an array is a fixed size structure if you expect it to work the same as in php you're just plainly wrong

Comment: it won't work as its just "put item at the end of the list", not "add one"

Comment: isn't foo.length the memory length of the array?

Comment: @chris what won't work is trying to access length index not length - 1

Comment: @Achshar Yes, but indexes are zero based, so `foo.Length` is the *length* of the array, but the indexes are [0..`foo.Length-1`].

Comment: I'm saying there's no need to explain to the OP why `foo[foo.Length]` won't work when the OP is aware enough of that to say it "obviously won't work".

Comment: I don't want it to work the *same* as php, I am just curious if there's a simpler way to go about doing it. Hence the question.

Comment: @RonBeyer oh yea right. An oversight on my part, my bad.

Comment: @chris maybe ; I didn't interpreted that like this though ; the intent could have been clearer with another message than just "won't work". that could be "won't resolve my issue" or "gives me an (unprecised) error" (and judging by OP comment the precision wasn't so superfluous)

Answer (score 0):

Originally I wrote this as a comment, but I think it contains enough important points to warrant writing it as an answer.

You seem to be under the impression that C# is an awkward language because you stubbornly insist on using an array while having the requirement that you should "push items onto the end", as evidenced by this comment:

> Isn't pushing items into the array kind of the entire purpose of the data structure?

To answer that: no, the purpose of the array data structure is to have a contiguous block of pre-allocated memory to mimic the original array structure in C(++) that you can easily index and perform pointer arithmetic on.

If you want a data structure that supports certain operations, such as pushing elements onto the end, consider a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, or, if you insist on avoiding generics, a `System.Collections.List`. There are specializations that specify the underlying storage structure (such as `ArrayList`) but in general the whole point of the C# library is that you don't want to concern yourself with such details: the `List<T>` class has certain guarantees on its operations (e.g. insertion is *O(n)*, retrieval is *O(1)* -- just like an array) and whether there is an array or some linked list that actually holds the data is irrelevant and is in fact dynamically decided based on the size and use case of the list at runtime.

Don't try to compare PHP and C# by comparing PHP arrays with C# arrays - they have different programming paradigms and the way to solve a problem in one does not necessarily carry over to the other.

To answer the question as written, I see two options then:

- Use arrays the awkward way. Either create an array of `Nullable<int>`s and accept some boxing / unboxing and unpleasant LINQ statements for insertion; or keep an additional counter (preferably wrapped up in a class together with the array) to keep track of the last assigned element.
- Use a proper data structure with appropriate guarantees on the operations that matter, such as `List<T>` which is effectively the (much better, optimised) built-in version of the second option above.

I understand that the latter option is not feasible for you because of the constraints imposed by your teacher, but then do not be surprised that things are harder than the canonical way in another language, if you are not allowed to use the canonical way in this language.

*Afterthought:*
A hybrid alternative that just came to mind, is using a List for storage and then just calling `.ToArray` on it. In your insert method, just `Add` to the list and return the new array.

Comment: Achshar didn't say that they hated List and were against the use of it. Said that it was a homework assignment and that it wasn't an option.

Comment: I think there are two people I am projecting here, me and my teacher. Me who has no problem with any of what you said, and my teacher who gave the array assignment and whom I am representing here. That confused people I guess. I should have been more careful in how I present my question.